# C++ help! Program won't work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, runtime-error

I've working on writing a program that calculate the hypotenuse of the triangle but somehow, I've come facing some unexpected error or more like runtime error and the sad part is that, I don't even know my own mistake. Anyway, here is my code and I will be  pleased for the answer

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//function prototype
double hypotenuse(double leg1, double leg2);
double leg(double hypotenuse, double leg);

void main()
{
    //local variable 
    double leg1;
    double leg2;

    //user interface
    cout << "Enter the first leg of the triangle: ";
    cin >> leg1;
    cout << "Enter the second leg of the triangle: ";
    cin >> leg2;
    cout << "The value of hypothesis is: " << hypotenuse(leg1,leg2) << endl;

    system("pause");
}

double hypothenuse(double leg1, double leg2)
{
    return ((leg1 * leg1) + (leg2 * leg2));
}
```

Comment: What error, exactly, have you run across?

Comment: so, your problem is that its calculating the wrong value, or something else?

Comment: well you did forget to take the square root there in the hypothenuse function.

Comment: it's not that, every time I would run this program it would give me error and that's not it, it wouldn't even highlight my mistake

Comment: @FrankConry Everything is right so far except it wouldn't run besides giving me the same error that visual studio does.

Comment: Please edit your post and include the details about the error. Does it return the wrong value? Does it crash? Does it make coffee instead of tea?

Comment: It just wouldn't compile it like everytime I run this program it gives me a error as in build error. Usually Viusal studio would find the errors for you but this one doesn't. Don't know why?

Comment: Imagine someone looking for a solution to the same problem you're facing. Are they going to google: "C++ program won't work!!!"? :)

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth My morning [Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=%22program+won't+work%22+site:stackoverflow.com&safe=active)...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your intent is to use old pythag, your function needs a sqrt call in it:

```
double hypothenuse(double leg1, double leg2){
    return sqrt((leg1 * leg1) + (leg2 * leg2));
}
```

This will of course require you to include the `<cmath>` header

Answer (score 2):

Spelling check please!

```
double hypo**te**nuse(double leg1, double leg2);

cout << "The value of hypothesis is: " << hypo**te**nuse(leg1,leg2) << endl;

double hypo**the**nuse(double leg1, double leg2)
{
    return ((leg1 * leg1) + (leg2 * leg2));
}
```

Comment: I was wondering why your compiler did not warned for it ;) 

If it fixes you problem, consider up-voting it and "accept answer".. You are welcome :)

Comment: I would've voted if I have enough reputation. LOL

Comment: Well you can still vote up and accept the answer if this fixes your issue... You don't need reputation to vote or accept ;)

Answer (score 2):

According to your code visual studio will give this error

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "double __cdecl hypotenuse(double,double)"  
(?hypotenuse@@YANNN@Z) referenced in function _main
```

because In function definition you have spelled `hypothenuse` but in function declaration you spelled it as `hypotenuse` (missing `h` from spelling).
 That is causing link time error because it cannot find the function definition of hypotenuse.
correct it and it will compile and make logical changes suggested by `RichardPlunkett`.